# When running load test for Kafka messaging with Jmeter from Jenkins server getting an error

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, jenkins-plugins

When running load test for kafka with jmeter from Jenkins server getting error:

```
  CannotResolveClassException: com.gslab.pepper.config.plaintext.PlainTextConfigElement
---- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
cause-message       : 
first-jmeter-class  : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:66)
class               : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
required-type       : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late reply. I resolved this issue-> I again downloaded the jars for Kafka-clients and pepper-box and put it into Jenkins again. Because previously, it was not downloaded completely via Jenkins from the download source. There was an issue with download sources address URLs.

Answer (score 1):

It indicates that your JMeter instance on Jenkins master (or slave) doesn't have [Pepper-Box - Kafka Load Generator](https://github.com/GSLabDev/pepper-box) plugin installed.

This plugin isn't managed by JMeter Plugins Manager so you will need to copy `pepper-box-x.x.jar` from you local machine to JMeter's "lib/ext" folder on Jenkins, if you're doing [Distributed testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) - you will need to copy the file to each JMeter slave machine

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually, I already downloaded two jars ->kafka-clients-1.0.0.jar & pepper-box-1.0.jar to JMeter's "lib/ext" folder on Jenkins. Then I found this issue.